# Lua find random key match in Table

Tags: lua

I have a chords table with chord Names and the Start time, there are many of the same Name at different Start times. I need to randomly choose a matching chord_name

```
chord_name = "Cm7b5"
time = chords[chord_name].Start
```

Comment: Since table can contain only one value at given key, and you use chord_name as the key, then there cannot be more than one chord of the same name. Are you sure that your table is _chords[chord_name]_ and not for example _chords[some_index].Name_?

Comment: Yes sorry that will do to get what I need, a random index that matches the name>  chords[some_index].Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you need to select a random `chord` from `chords` so that `chords[index].Name == chord_name` and your indexes are one after another like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (and not for example: 52, 96, 121) you could do:

```lua
chord_name = "Cm7b5"

index = math.random(#chords)
while chords[index].Name ~= chord_name do
    index = math.random(#chords)
end

time = chords[index].Start
```

*(Note that I don't select a chord, rather a `.Start` time as your example shows that.)*

This however has a very high chance of (nearly) infinite looping if you have alot of data and only a handful has a `.Name == chord_name`.

So it is a great idea to make sure that single call to `math.random()` will give us a definite answer (index).

```lua
chord_name = "Cm7b5"

--we create an empty table
indexes = {}

--and store all indexes that fulfil the condition chords[index].Name == chord_name
for index, chord in pairs(chords) do
    if chord.Name == chord_name then
        table.insert(indexes, index)
    end
end

--now we can randomly select from this table
index = indexes[math.random(#indexes)]

--which will always yield an index pointing to a chord with .Name == chord_name
time = chords[index].Start
```

Note that using `pairs(chords)` also allows to select chords from tables with holes (i.e. `{[1] = "a", [5] = "b", [16] = "c"}`).

The latter solution might on the other hand prove problematic if you have a lot (probably millions or 100k) of data. Iterating the whole table and selecting matching names and creating a new table based on that is going to be very time and memory consuming.